# nginx 301 redirects not working as expected

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I have added the following rules to my nginx.conf file

```
rewrite ^/top100/Armin%20van%20Buuren/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/armin-van-buuren/$1 redirect;
rewrite ^/top100/armin-van-buuren/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/armin-van-buuren/$1 redirect;
rewrite ^/top100/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 redirect;
```

For the 1st rule it redirects to `www.example.com/top100/Armin%20van%20Buuren/` to `www.example.com/Armin%20van%20Buuren/`

The other 2 rules are working fine. What did I mess up here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx uses internally normalized URIs :

> The matching is performed against a normalized URI, after decoding the text encoded in the “%XX” form, resolving references to relative path components “.” and “..”, and possible compression of two or more adjacent slashes into a single slash.

Use (single or double) quotation marks to wrap the space in a string.

So it would be :

```
rewrite "^/top100/Armin van Buuren/(.*)$" /armin-van-buuren/$1 redirect;
```

Comment: So it'll be something like `rewrite ^"/top100/Armin van Buuren/"(.*)$ http://www.example.com/armin-van-buuren/$1 redirect;`?

Comment: @YinYang More something like `rewrite "^/top100/Armin van Buuren/(.*)$" /armin-van-buuren/$1 redirect;`